# Nginx proxy with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have 3 servers Minio on a server (port 9001, 9002 and 9003)

But I only have the port 80 opened.

I'm trying to redirect client on Minio 1 2 or 3 depending on the url something like this:

http://url/1 -> redirect on 127.0.0.1:9001
http://url/2 -> redirect on 127.0.0.1:9002
http://url/3 -> redirect on 127.0.0.1:9003

My problem is that Minio servers redirect themselves to http://url/minio/ wich create a 404 error.

I really don't know how to configure my nginx for these redirections.

If you have an idea it could be great

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to change the Minio configuration so that their base URL matches the one you are ultimately using in nginx.

Comment: I think about that too but there is no config line in the minio configuration to specify a base URL

Comment: Please refer this for more information https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/5947